# Elasticsearch autogenerated _id starting with hyphen is not searchable

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch I have document that has autogenerated _id field. I need to search by this _id. Unfortunately, when the _id is autogenerated with a hypen as the first character, it can not be searched. Should I set a mapping on this field? (so far I have no mapping for this whole index)

See following example which I got by GETting `http://localhost:9200/cazv/issue/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*`

```
..., {
      "_index" : "cazv",
      "_type" : "issue",
      "_id" : "vvQWnjYqSU2GJ4hrRnOBXw",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"volumeId": "At8YmsUdRqmqX-OUJKvdcQ",
"number": "No. 3"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "cazv",
      "_type" : "issue",
      "_id" : "-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"volumeId": "Z97A5vG8TOSl7Bv0UlFGYg",
"number": "No. 1"}
    }
, ...
```

When I try to find the first issue, no problem using `http://localhost:9200/cazv/issue/_search?pretty=true&q=_id:vvQWnjYqSU2GJ4hrRnOBXw`

I get

```
{
  "took" : 137,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "cazv",
      "_type" : "issue",
      "_id" : "vvQWnjYqSU2GJ4hrRnOBXw",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"volumeId": "At8YmsUdRqmqX-OUJKvdcQ",
"number": "No. 3"}
    } ]
  }
}
```

But when I try to get the second issue by getting `http://localhost:9200/cazv/issue/_search?pretty=true&q=_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg`

I get an error instead:

```
{
  "error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[NfwFTkfwTAuyO6QGG9hUUw][cazv][0]: SearchParseException[[cazv][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg\",\"lowercase_expanded_terms\":true,\"analyze_wildcard\":false}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[cazv] Failed to parse query [_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg': Encountered \" \"-\" \"- \"\" at line 1, column 4.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    <BAREOPER> ...\r\n    \"(\" ...\r\n    \"*\" ...\r\n    <QUOTED> ...\r\n    <TERM> ...\r\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\r\n    <WILDTERM> ...\r\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\r\n    \"[\" ...\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    <NUMBER> ...\r\n    ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered \" \"-\" \"- \"\" at line 1, column 4.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    <BAREOPER> ...\r\n    \"(\" ...\r\n    \"*\" ...\r\n    <QUOTED> ...\r\n    <TERM> ...\r\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\r\n    <WILDTERM> ...\r\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\r\n    \"[\" ...\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    <NUMBER> ...\r\n    ]; }{[NfwFTkfwTAuyO6QGG9hUUw][cazv][1]: SearchParseException[[cazv][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg\",\"lowercase_expanded_terms\":true,\"analyze_wildcard\":false}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[cazv] Failed to parse query [_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg': Encountered \" \"-\" \"- \"\" at line 1, column 4.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    <BAREOPER> ...\r\n    \"(\" ...\r\n    \"*\" ...\r\n    <QUOTED> ...\r\n    <TERM> ...\r\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\r\n    <WILDTERM> ...\r\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\r\n    \"[\" ...\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    <NUMBER> ...\r\n    ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered \" \"-\" \"- \"\" at line 1, column 4.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    <BAREOPER> ...\r\n    \"(\" ...\r\n    \"*\" ...\r\n    <QUOTED> ...\r\n    <TERM> ...\r\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\r\n    <WILDTERM> ...\r\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\r\n    \"[\" ...\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    <NUMBER> ...\r\n    ]; }{[NfwFTkfwTAuyO6QGG9hUUw][cazv][2]: SearchParseException[[cazv][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg\",\"lowercase_expanded_terms\":true,\"analyze_wildcard\":false}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[cazv] Failed to parse query [_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg': Encountered \" \"-\" \"- \"\" at line 1, column 4.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    <BAREOPER> ...\r\n    \"(\" ...\r\n    \"*\" ...\r\n    <QUOTED> ...\r\n    <TERM> ...\r\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\r\n    <WILDTERM> ...\r\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\r\n    \"[\" ...\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    <NUMBER> ...\r\n    ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered \" \"-\" \"- \"\" at line 1, column 4.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    <BAREOPER> ...\r\n    \"(\" ...\r\n    \"*\" ...\r\n    <QUOTED> ...\r\n    <TERM> ...\r\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\r\n    <WILDTERM> ...\r\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\r\n    \"[\" ...\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    <NUMBER> ...\r\n    ]; }{[NfwFTkfwTAuyO6QGG9hUUw][cazv][3]: SearchParseException[[cazv][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg\",\"lowercase_expanded_terms\":true,\"analyze_wildcard\":false}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[cazv] Failed to parse query [_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg': Encountered \" \"-\" \"- \"\" at line 1, column 4.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    <BAREOPER> ...\r\n    \"(\" ...\r\n    \"*\" ...\r\n    <QUOTED> ...\r\n    <TERM> ...\r\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\r\n    <WILDTERM> ...\r\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\r\n    \"[\" ...\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    <NUMBER> ...\r\n    ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered \" \"-\" \"- \"\" at line 1, column 4.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    <BAREOPER> ...\r\n    \"(\" ...\r\n    \"*\" ...\r\n    <QUOTED> ...\r\n    <TERM> ...\r\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\r\n    <WILDTERM> ...\r\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\r\n    \"[\" ...\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    <NUMBER> ...\r\n    ]; }{[NfwFTkfwTAuyO6QGG9hUUw][cazv][4]: SearchParseException[[cazv][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg\",\"lowercase_expanded_terms\":true,\"analyze_wildcard\":false}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[cazv] Failed to parse query [_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '_id:-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg': Encountered \" \"-\" \"- \"\" at line 1, column 4.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    <BAREOPER> ...\r\n    \"(\" ...\r\n    \"*\" ...\r\n    <QUOTED> ...\r\n    <TERM> ...\r\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\r\n    <WILDTERM> ...\r\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\r\n    \"[\" ...\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    <NUMBER> ...\r\n    ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered \" \"-\" \"- \"\" at line 1, column 4.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    <BAREOPER> ...\r\n    \"(\" ...\r\n    \"*\" ...\r\n    <QUOTED> ...\r\n    <TERM> ...\r\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\r\n    <WILDTERM> ...\r\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\r\n    \"[\" ...\r\n    \"{\" ...\r\n    <NUMBER> ...\r\n    ]; }]",
  "status" : 400
}
```

Comment: Solved by using quotes in the query:
`http://localhost:9200/cazv/issue/_search?pretty=true&q=_id:"-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg"`
maybe it would be better to encode double quotes, so the URL would look like this:
`http://localhost:9200/cazv/issue/_search?pretty=true&q=_id:%22-yTCu-HxSkOhwDOp4JVblg%22`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using the query parser which interprets the `-` as a NOT prefix operator and I personally think it's the second - that it get's confused on. you might wanna put quotes around the term or just use a term query on the id field or just put it in the url `/index/type/id`

simon

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, so i used the mapping to override the _id with my ProductId.
In your case set the _id to volumeId, but i dont know if your volumeId is unique.

Mapping:

```
{ 
 "issue" : {
  "_id" : {
    "path" : "volumeId"
  }
}
```

After the mapping:

```
..., {
  "_index" : "cazv",
  "_type" : "issue",
  "_id" : "At8YmsUdRqmqX-OUJKvdcQ",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"volumeId": "At8YmsUdRqmqX-OUJKvdcQ","number": "No. 3"}
}, {
  "_index" : "cazv",
  "_type" : "issue",
  "_id" : "Z97A5vG8TOSl7Bv0UlFGYg",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"volumeId": "Z97A5vG8TOSl7Bv0UlFGYg","number": "No. 1"}
}
```

I hope that helps.